# LINQ query format conversion from VB to .Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

Can anyone suggest me a better way to convert following LINQ query from VB to C#.

```
ws.GetADGroups().Select(Function(x) If(ws.GetOUAdGroup(x.GroupName, OUId), New    ADUserGroup() With {.IsChecked = True, .GroupName = x.GroupName, .SortOrder = x.SortOrder}, New ADUserGroup() With {.IsChecked = False, .GroupName = x.GroupName, .SortOrder = x.SortOrder})).ToList()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ws.GetADGroups().Select(x => ws.GetOUAdGroup(x.GroupName, OUId) ? new ADUserGroup {
 IsChecked = true,
 GroupName = x.GroupName,
 SortOrder = x.SortOrder
} : new ADUserGroup {
 IsChecked = false,
 GroupName = x.GroupName,
 SortOrder = x.SortOrder
}).ToList();`

Comment: You're title is a little misleading. .NET is the framework. Both VB and C# use this framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try **Code Converter** from Telerik [here](http://converter.telerik.com/). You can easily convert VB to C# code and vice versa

[image]

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: I have a problem with this